# Element composition in list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
s = ['dog','cat','horse, cat, pig','horse, giraffe, dog']
x = 'giraffe'
if x in s:
    print('1')
else:
    print('0')
```

getting 0's. How can I have it return 1 if I enter just a part of what an element contains?

Answer (score 3):

This might work

```
for element in s:
    if x in element: 
        print('1')
        break
else: 
   print('0')
```

Comment: +1.  Perhaps simpler is: `print('1' if any(x in item for item in x) else '0')`.

Comment: Correction from prior comment:  `print('1' if any(x in item for item in s) else '0')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if x in ', '.join(s).split(', '):
# ', '.join(s) returns:
# 'dog, cat, horse, cat, pig, horse, giraffe, dog' (a string)
#
# .split(', ') returns:
# ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'cat', 'pig', 'horse', 'giraffe', 'dog']
```

Your code is not giving you what you want because `s` contains:

```
'horse, giraffe, dog'
```

as a string, so

```
giraffe in ['dog', 'cat', 'horse, giraffe, dog']
```

will return `False`.

Comment: +1 for the join split... might break easily though as the data is clearly malformed.   Explicitly looking for item as in @Darth Kotik's answer problably clearer and more robust.